# Ajax response not working when mysql_query has "AND" in it

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

so this is my problems short version:

**This works:**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `some_table` 
                     WHERE IF (LENGTH('$some_variable') > 0, `$other_variable` LIKE
                               '%$some_variable%' , 0)");
```

I get a result go through it with a while pack it all in an array and with json_encode send it back to my ajax file, where i list the result. And it works perfectly.

But when i ad one more thing to the query it just gives back empty, so **this doesn't work:**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM `some_table` 
                      WHERE `something` = `some_other_thing` AND 
                          IF (LENGTH('$some_variable') > 0, `$other_variable` 
                               LIKE '%$some_variable%' , 0)");
```

So with that **AND** things just don't work, but only whit ajax, i mean if i simply print the array out php works superbly.

Thanks in advance.

This is the rest of my php

```
while ($value = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$result[] = array
            (       
                gyarto => $value['gyarto'],
                termekcsalad => $value['termekcsalad'],
                kiszereles => $value['kiszereles']
            );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

and my jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                    url:"updates/isu.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: form,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {


                    $.each(data, function(i)                            
                    {
                       $("#result table").append('<tr><td>'+data[i].gyarto+' '+data[i].termekcsalad+' '+data[i].kiszereles+'</td></tr>');

                    }); 

                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: You must be print JSON in response of AJAX, print JSON and see if its valid.

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the PHP code and the AJAX code als well?

Comment: @11684 i will post it now, one second

Comment: Example data (preferably in the form of `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` statements) would be helpful...

Comment: if the query works in standalone browser page but not in AJAX.. where's the javascript code for AJAX that sends the data ? Sounds like problem has nothing to do with query statement but with variable values passed in to it that you aren't sending correctly from client

Comment: @charlietfl i just serialize the form and send it in that form variable, but i checked it and it works... like i said ... everything works perfectly until i ad an "AND" to the query

Comment: OK..but your statement says that it worked in standalone page but not when called by AJAX. So either AJAX has nothing to do with the question whatsoever or there is a problem with data transfer or parsing

Comment: @charlietfl sorry maybe i miss typed but it the fact is it works in ajax and in php if the query has no "AND" otherwise it works only in php, i mean standalone page

Comment: @charlietfl but how can it be purely a query issue when in a standalone page the query works with "AND"

Comment: OK.. then it is a data issue in AJAX. Try sending back just the query string to see what it looks like. You can look at it in a browser console. Also double check all the form data in the request in console. Sounds like a mismatch somewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I think you are mixing php language in a mysql query.
```

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROMsome_table WHEREsomething=some_other_thing AND  (LENGTH('$some_variable') > 0 AND '$other_variable` LIKE '%$some_variable%')");
```

Also here is an exemple on how to use the mysql_fetch_array

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row["id"], $row["name"]);
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url:"updates/isu.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: form,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                       // console.log(data);
                        $.each(data, function(i)                            
                        {
                           $("#result table").append('<tr><td>'+data[i].gyarto+' '+data[i].termekcsalad+' '+data[i].kiszereles+'</td></tr>');
                        }); 
                    }
                });

Comment: This still doesnt work when i send it back with json_encode i  dont get anything, yet with only php it works... I mean it works with how you wrote bu i need an "AND" in the query

Comment: yes yes of course like i said, when i print it in standalon php page it give back the good result's

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 $sql = "SELECT *, LENGTH('$some_variable') as 'length_of_var'  
                     FROM some_table 
                     WHERE something=some_other_thing AND 
                           length_of_var > 0 AND 
                           `$other_variable` LIKE '%$some_variable%';";


 die($sql);//we will stop here and see how the query looks like.. If it's an AJAX request, you will need to check in your browser console. Use firebug or chrome developer tools.

$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Can you also log the sql string before it's executed and share. This can help you see how the query looks like before it's executed, then we can modify it, then edit your php code to fix any issues. It cold be that some variables you're concatenating to the SQL query are empty strings or null, etc.

Comment: Why? Once you understand what you did wrong you can avoid it next time

Comment: @mwangi this doesn't work for my shoud length of var be something ?

Comment: it's a wrong query, you cann't use aliases inside `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Calculate length of `$some_variable` in php, Why do you use mysql `LENGTH`? Just separate your queries if you can detect in PHP that length of `$some_variable` is greter 0:

```
if (strlen($some_variable) > 0) {
   mysql_query("
      SELECT * 
      FROM `some_table` 
      WHERE `something` = `some_other_thing`
        AND `$other_variable` LIKE '%$some_variable%'")
} else {
   // do nothing because your where clause has condition like: something = another AND 0
   // so for each row it's false
}
```

Comment: @Serijio sorry but still doesn't work, I really think it's the "AND" from the query because with out that it works

Comment: What does `$other_variable` contain? Static strin or sql query or field name? Maybe it contains single or double quote?

Comment: @Mr.Sam Can you provide us with resulting SQL query? Just run `echo $your_php_with_sql_string`

Answer (score 0):

Using some "synthetic" example data the query works "as assumed"

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test')  or die(mysql_error());
setup();

$other_variable = 'foo';
$some_variable = 'hell';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM `some_table` 
                      WHERE `something` = `some_other_thing` AND 
                          IF (LENGTH('$some_variable') > 0, `$other_variable` 
                               LIKE '%$some_variable%' , 0)");                          
if (!$query) die(mysql_error());
while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) ) {
    echo join(', ', $row), "\n";
}

function setup() {
    mysql_query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE some_table ( 
            id int auto_increment,
            something int,
            some_other_thing int,
            foo varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO some_table (something, some_other_thing, foo) VALUES
        (1, 1, 'hello'),
        (1, 1, 'lalala'),
        (2, 2, 'hellboy')
    ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

prints

```
1, 1, 1, hello
3, 2, 2, hellboy
```

but I doubt that the query does what you intend it to do.
E.g. if `$some_variable` is empty it's easier to test that on the php side and skip the query completely - no record can fullfil the conditions ever in that case.